# Get dynamic key value from an array angularjs

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, underscore.js

I have a mongo collection called settings

```
      {
  "_id": "123",
  "type": "subject",
  "name": "Main",
  "list": [{
    "_id": "123",
    "name": "Maths"
  }, {
    "_id": "123",
    "name": " Physics"
  }]
}

{
  "_id": "123",
  "type": "exam",
  "name": "Activities",
  "list": [{
    "_id": "123",
    "name": "Reading"
  }, {
    "_id": "123",
    "name": "Fluency"
  }]
}
```

Note: the values provided in my mongo is only for reference purpose.

Now I have generated an array with the records in settings collection

```
      self.sample = function() {
            self.settingsObj = {}
                // console.log(self.settings)
            _.each(self.settings, function(settings) {
                //_.each(self.settings, function(settings) {

                if (!self.settingsObj[settings.type]) {
                    self.settingsObj[settings.type] = []
                }
                self.settingsObj[settings.type] = settings.list
            })

            console.log(self.settingsObj)

        }
```

When I console the **settingsObj** I get result like this in my console

```
Object {subject: Array[2], exam: Array[2]}
```

Now I want to loop this inside a scope variable

```
   $scope.search = [{
                        "name": "",
                        "data": ""
}]
```

inside this name i want to get the object name in this situation subject,exam and inside loop i want to loop the arrays for subject and exam.

I tried another `._each`, and I got the key and value but how can I loop them correctly.

Otherwise please help me in generating subject and exams as different array

Comment: `Object {subject: Array[2], exam: Array[2]}` where is `subject and exam` in the db structure? In what level they are? Please update the db structure or the fields in sample outputs.

Comment: subject and exam is type in db structure

Comment: Ok. did not notice that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure if I understand your question.

But if I see well you're using a Lodash.js library so I provide below script using a lodash:

I assume that you have settings variable like this:

```
var settings =     [ {
    "_id": "123",
    "type": "subject",
    "name": "Main",
    "list": [{
        "_id": "123",
        "name": "Maths"
    }, {
        "_id": "123",
        "name": " Physics"
    }]
}
,
{
    "_id": "123",
        "type": "exam",
        "name": "Activities",
        "list": [{
    "_id": "123",
    "name": "Reading"
}, {
    "_id": "123",
    "name": "Fluency"
}]
}];
```

And I create functions for process those settings:

```
function createSearch(settings){
    return _(settings).flatMap(toSearchArray).value();
}

function toSearchArray(setting){
    return _(setting.list).map("name").map(toSearchObject).value()

    function toSearchObject(data){
        return {
            name: setting.type,
            data: data
        }
    }
}
```

And when you call `createSearch(settings)`
you will receive this result:

```
[
  {
    "name": "subject",
    "data": "Maths"
  },
  {
    "name": "subject",
    "data": " Physics"
  },
  {
    "name": "exam",
    "data": "Reading"
  },
  {
    "name": "exam",
    "data": "Fluency"
  }
]
```

Hopefully this is what you need.